# Image resizing makes Button unclickable

Tags: image, swiftui, scrollview

I have a simple scrollview with a SDWebImage pulling in Firebase URL links to display images. For some bizarre reason, when I do not give a specific frame to my images, I can click on the button positioned in the bottom left corner. But when I give it a max height or any height at all, the button becomes unclickable. This seriously might be the weirdest SwiftUI issue I have ever seen - any help would be great.

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct Test2FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewmodel = FeedViewModel()
    @State var show : Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
          VStack(spacing:5) {
                ForEach(viewmodel.posts){ post in
                    ZStack(alignment:.bottomLeading) {
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: post.original_posted_image))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(maxHeight:440)
                            .clipped()
                        Button(action: {
                            show.toggle()
                        }){
                            Text("PRESS ME")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $show) {
            Text("hey")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Button becomes unclickable because the result of `.clipped()` is only visual — in reality, the image spans all the way 'above' the button, thus is being used for hit testing. You should use `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to disable that.

```swift
WebImage(url: URL(string: post.original_posted_image))
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(maxHeight:440)
    .clipped()
    .allowsHitTesting(false) // <- here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it really helped me out! By the way, do you know if this is some kind of bug in SwiftUI? Just curious, did you stumble upon it by trial and error?

Comment: 2023 and this is still a thing. This saved me from wasting more time, thx!

Answer (score -1):

try putting the `.frame(maxHeight:440)` just before `.scaledToFill()`, works for me.